# Stash List with Grid and Entry Title

Tags: stash, grid, list

I'm trying to display two columns of EE entries, each entry has a grid field with a text field and an Assets field. I thought I was close on this, but clearly I'm missing the boat because the grid portion isn't spitting anything out :(

```
{embed="_layout/main"}
{preload_replace:the_channel="publications"}
{exp:stash:set_value name="title" value="Publications"}

{exp:stash:set name="content"}
<h1>Publications</h1>

<p class="lead-in">{lv_publications_leadin}</p>

{exp:stash:set_list name="pub" parse_tags="yes" save="yes" scope="site"}
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="{the_channel}"
    disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination"
    limit="20"
    sort="desc"
    status="Open"
    show_future_entries="yes"
}
        {stash:publication_title}{title}{/stash:publication_title}

        {exp:stash:set_list:nested name="entry_files" context="{entry_id}" parse_tags="yes"}    
            {publication}
                {stash:publication_year}{publication:year}{/stash:publication_year}
                {stash:publication_file}{publication:file}{/stash:publication_file}
            {/publication}
        {/exp:stash:set_list:nested}

{/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set_list}

<div class="w-row">
    <div class="w-col w-col-6">
        {exp:stash:get_list name="pub" sort="desc" limit="1/2"}
        <div class="_97 card">
            <h4>{publication_title}</h4>
            <ul class="card-list">
                {exp:stash:get_list:nested name="entry_files" context="{item_entry_id}" prefix="nested"}
                <a href="{publication_file}"><li>{publication_year} {publication_title}</li></a>
                {/exp:stash:get_list:nested}

            </ul>
        </div>
        {/exp:stash:get_list}
    </div>
    <div class="w-col w-col-6">
        {exp:stash:get_list name="pub" sort="desc" offset="1/2" limit="1/2"}
        <div class="card">
             <h4>{publication_title}</h4>
            <ul class="card-list">

                {exp:stash:get_list:nested name="entry_files" context="{item_entry_id}" prefix="nested"}
                <a href="{publication_file}"><li>{publication_year} {publication_title}</li></a>
                {/exp:stash:get_list:nested}

            </ul>
        </div>
        {/exp:stash:get_list}
    </div>

</div>
{/exp:stash:set}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suspect it is because you are using different context settings between setting the list and getting it back again.

You set the list using `{entry_id}` as the context.
You retrieve the list using `{item_entry_id}` as the context.

But you don't seem to be setting / saving the value `{item_entry_id}`.

If you are basing this code on the examples on the [lists page of the stash wiki](https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/Lists), you'll see that in those the examples explicitly store the `{item_entry_id}` value based on `{entry_id}` as follows in the example given on that page:

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="my_list" parse_tags="yes" parse_depth="2"}
    {exp:channel:entries channel="clients" limit="5"}

        {stash:item_title}{title}{/stash:item_title}
        {stash:item_entry_id}{entry_id}{/stash:item_entry_id}

        {exp:stash:set_list:nested name="related_entries" context="{entry_id}" parse_tags="yes"}
            {!-- this could be a Matrix or Playa tag pair --}
            {contact_docs}
                {stash:related_title}{mx_title}{/stash:related_title}
            {/contact_docs}
        {/exp:stash:set_list:nested}    

    {/exp:channel:entries}  
{/exp:stash:set_list}
```

HTH

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that one line that ended up guiding me to the solution! I ended up changing this from a grid to a matrix field, along with adding the prefix "nested" to my matrix fields in the stash get_list portion. Here is my working code in case it helps anyone else.

Comment: Great - glad you got it working

Answer (score 0):

```
    {embed="_layout/main"}
{preload_replace:the_channel="publications"}
{exp:stash:set_value name="title" value="Publications"}

{exp:stash:set name="content"}
<h1>Publications</h1>

<p class="lead-in">{lv_publications_leadin}</p>

{exp:stash:set_list name="pub" parse_tags="yes" parse_depth="2"}
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="{the_channel}"
    disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination"
    limit="20"
    sort="desc"
    status="Open"
    show_future_entries="yes"
}
        {stash:publication_title}{title}{/stash:publication_title}
        {stash:item_entry_id}{entry_id}{/stash:item_entry_id}
        {exp:stash:set_list:nested name="entry_files" context="{entry_id}" parse_tags="yes"}    
            {publication}
                {stash:publication_year}{year}{/stash:publication_year}
                {stash:publication_file}{file}{/stash:publication_file}
            {/publication}
        {/exp:stash:set_list:nested}

{/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set_list}

<div class="w-row">
    <div class="w-col w-col-6">
        {exp:stash:get_list name="pub" sort="desc" limit="1/2"}
        <div class="_97 card">
            <h4>{publication_title}</h4>
            <ul class="card-list">
                {exp:stash:get_list:nested name="entry_files" context="{item_entry_id}" prefix="nested"}
                <a href="{nested:publication_file}"><li>{nested:publication_year} {publication_title}</li></a>
                {/exp:stash:get_list:nested}

            </ul>
        </div>
        {/exp:stash:get_list}
    </div>
    <div class="w-col w-col-6">
        {exp:stash:get_list name="pub" sort="desc" offset="1/2" limit="1/2"}
        <div class="card">
             <h4>{publication_title}</h4>
            <ul class="card-list">

                {exp:stash:get_list:nested name="entry_files" context="{item_entry_id}" prefix="nested"}
                <a href="{nested:publication_file}"><li>{nested:publication_year} {publication_title}</li></a>
                {/exp:stash:get_list:nested}

            </ul>
        </div>
        {/exp:stash:get_list}
    </div>

</div>
{/exp:stash:set}
```

My working code mentioned above.